# Adjust Container height to maximum height of a child in a Row

Tags: flutter, layout

[image]

I have several `Row` elements. Each `Row` contains some `Container` elements. I want the `Container` elements to be expanded to the current height of the `Row`.

For example: In the last `Row` I want all children to have the height of element `87`.

I tried a lot:

- Container `height` to `double.infinity`
- Container `constraints` to `BoundContraints.expand()`
- Using `IntrinsicHeight()`:

  IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: myContainers
  )
  )

However, all of these approaches yield exceptions because the entire height raised to infinity or - in case of the `IntrinsicHeight` approach returned

> LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

I guess, this is because I have no explicit maxHeight set for the entire tool.

So, I want to keep the actual `Row` height, but want to expand its children.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and why not using simple `Stack` with `Positioned` children?

Comment: @pskink: Because it yield the same problem: How would I know the required height a-priori? I would have set a fictive height. Now the row height is dynamically set to the height of the dynamically set height of a child. I don't know about the final height before it wasn't created.

Comment: @pskink the font sizes are dynamically set to fit the fixed container sizes. They are ok as they are. But they result in different height. My goal is as decribed: Keep the current row height but adjust the children heights to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a Table? Looks like the right thing.

Comment: oh no! :D I never was aware of the Table widget! I don't know why, but that would be the solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are more approaches.You can wrap your Row with fixed sized container like this.Width gets the current device width.

```
Container(
  width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height:87,
  Row(
    children:[]
  )
)
```

OR You can create like this.Here I have used device width/20 as the size of the container or you can customise it using your own width.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Answer());
  }
}

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              RowItem(
                count: '1',
                txt: "H",
              ),
              Spacer(),
              RowItem(
                count: '2',
                txt: "He",
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              RowItem(
                count: '3',
                txt: "Li",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '4',
                txt: "Be",
              ),
              Spacer(),
              RowItem(
                count: '5',
                txt: "B",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '6',
                txt: "C",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '7',
                txt: "N",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '8',
                txt: "O",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '9',
                txt: "F",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '10',
                txt: "Ne",
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              RowItem(
                count: '11',
                txt: "Na",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '12',
                txt: "Mg",
              ),
              Spacer(),
              RowItem(
                count: '13',
                txt: "Al",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '14',
                txt: "Si",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '15',
                txt: "P",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '16',
                txt: "S",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '17',
                txt: "Cl",
              ),
              RowItem(
                count: '18',
                txt: "Ar",
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String txt;
  final String count;
  RowItem({@required this.txt, @required this.count});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 87,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20,
      child: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(count),
          SizedBox(
            height: 2,
          ),
          Text(txt)
        ],
      )),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
    );
  }
}
```

check the result here.
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuyjZ.png)

Comment: Well, as I can see, this requires to know about the row height before the calculation, correct? This is in my example not possible. I don't even know how the height will be. I just want to keep the current Row height as it is and would like to adjust all children to it.

Comment: No.in my code the row does not depend on the height.only thing is is the container height.It will depend on its child container height.you can change its size by adding variable to it.then you can assign balues to that container in creation

Comment: Did you tried warapping conatiner by Expanded widget

Comment: Expanded will not work since it would use infinity height.

Comment: Try to use constrained box widget.

Comment: Have you considered a Table?  Looks like the right thing.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz oh no! :D I never was aware of the Table widget! I don't know why, but that would be the solution! Please add this as answer, if you like - i can accept this then!